# Is it valid to initialize global llvm values from outside the execution engine by writing to its address?

Tags: c++, llvm

I want to make a more or less complex calculation engine. To do this, I want to try out LLVM and its ExecutionEngine. I need to pass state (e.g. function pointers to external C functions or initialization values for the calculation) into it. Some of it may change during 2 calculation runs.

Is it allowed to create global variables for that, fetch its address and write to it?

Regards
Tobias

Comment: Why don't you just generate several functions with different constants?

Comment: Why not have get and set accessor functions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is as intended but it works.